# What are the steps involved in the solution to $\int{x^{-a} (b -cx^{-d})^e }dx$?

Tags: integration, integral-transforms, integral-operators

Mathematica gives me the following solution to $\int{x^{-a} (b -cx^{-d})^e }$:

$$\int{x^{-a} (b -cx^{-d})^e dx} = -\frac{b^{e}x^{1-a} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{a-1}{d},-e;\frac{a+d-1}{d};\frac{c x^{-d}}{b}\right)}{a-1},$$
where $a,b,c,d,e > 0$.

I'd like to figure out what are the steps involved in this solution.

I started by finding the Taylor's expansion of the integrand, but it doesn't seem to be the right way to follow.

Comment: *Hint*: Do this basic integral first: $$\int (1-z)^u z^v\;dz = \frac{z^{v+1}}{v+1}\;{}_2F_1(-u,v+1;v+2;z)+C$$if $|z|<1$.

Comment: The "step" is the introduction of the new variable $y=(c/b)x^{-d}$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, dear, is there a reference for that integral? A book or paper, for example?

Comment: Does someone know a reference for the integral presented by @GeraldEdgar?

Comment: The solution is now found at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4382276/442 in two answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof starts by applying the change of variable $z=(c/b)x^{-d}$ and then using the following identity
$$\int (1-z)^{u} z^{v} dz = \frac{z^{v+1}}{v+1} \, _2F_1(-u, v+1; v+2; z), |x|<1,$$
the proof is concluded.